# jQuery .accordion() Doesn't Work because jQuery Not Loading into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read everything on the web as well as everything on Stack Overflow. I've modified my code many times and my code STILL doesn't work! I'm going crazy because jQuery shouldn't be this difficult!

Just to clarify, the accordion function does not even show up on the page. All my HTML and CSS work perfectly. All I see on the page is headings and paragraphs. The paragraphs are supposed to act as an accordion when the headings are clicked.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.png">
    <title>Services</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#accordion').accordion();
             })
    </script>
  </head>

    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <h2 style="font-size:40px">Web Development</h2>
            <div>
                <p style="font-size:30px">Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text</p>
            </div>

            <h2 style="font-size:40px">Mobile Development</h2>
            <div>
                <p style="font-size:30px">Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text</p>
            </div>

            <h2 style="font-size:40px">SEO</h2>
            <div>
                <p style="font-size:30px">Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that for some reason, jQuery is not loading into my HTML. How should I fix this?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: The accordion function doesn't work. All I see on my page is headers and paragraphs. The paragraphs are supposed to toggle up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the jquery and jquery-ui scripts definition in your code with these:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is for the script to go underneath the html code. Another important thing is to use window.onload() instead of .ready(). This worked for me two days ago :)

This allows the code to run once the page has completely loaded:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by putting the script underneath the HTML code?

Comment: The best practice is to have <script>...</script> underneath the body tag or before closing the body. But in your case using window.onload should work.

Comment: neither putting the script in the body or window.onload worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').accordion();
});
```

Could you please run this code: 
My guess is, that one of those are not loaded:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
   alert("Jquery loaded");
} else {
    alert("not loaded");// jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Comment: jquery is not loaded according to the message

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I think that you searching [this](http://jsbin.com/fidof/1/edit)

I add

```
{ fillSpace: true, collapsible: true ,active: false}
```

Then the script is :

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#accordion').accordion({ fillSpace: true, collapsible: true ,active: false});
             });
    </script>
```

You can read the difference of collapsible and fillspace on [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion)

Click on **Collapse content** and **Fill Space** in the right of the image for see the difference.

Comment: Why not use Inspect element (right-click on browser and find the error) or use Firebug for Mozilla

Comment: And what you version of browser using? @bkhosh2

Comment: Chrome 34.0.1847.116, Firefox 28.0, and Safari 7.0.3

Answer (score 0):

try this as jQuery library:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

instead of those one:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

source:[Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default)